# SQL Script to: Automatic DML Export from Oracle Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-replication, dml

I have to sync two databases.
Database 1 has data I would like to use to sync everything. For example,

> > select * from administration.operations
> > where asset_no = '555'
> > --Suppose this query returns an asset with five rows of data in the "operations" table.

Database 2 can only be synced by using a dml statement. Which I've been creating by running a query like the one above on Dbase 1, then CTRL+A > Right Click > Export. This opens the export wizard, wherein I enter the appropriate table name "operations" in the 'Table Name' field (it default-fills to "EXPORT TABLE", which would not work). Because of primary keys and parent/child relationships, I generally have to run this process on 5-10 tables in order to ensure the second database is getting all the data related to asset_no=555. After I've run the query on all the relevant tables and copy/pasted the exported 'insert' statements in a dml, I can send it to the other server and now asset number 555 looks the same on database 2 as it looks on database 1.

I would really like to automate this process, since I do this anywhere from 10-30 asset_no's a day- that's 50-300 times a day I'm having to select * > Export Wizard > copy/paste into dml. I would love to automate this process. Is it possible to create a sql script to pull the select * results and automatically create the export commands without the user (me) having to click around so much?

I've tried writing scripts to generate the INSERT statements but some of the tables I have to sync contain 70+ columns- it's just not feasible, so I'd like something dynamic. With that in mind, I've never heard of a sql script that can do the same as the Export Wizard. So here we are. I also cannot use python or any other language to register mouse clicks or anything like that- the whole thing would have to be a sql statement that runs within Oracle.

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be done with DML statements in a script, and not with datapump? You can also look at SQLcl and `set sqlformat insert` to generate the insert statements, and flashback queries to get a consistent point-in-time state from multiple tables - unless that doesn't count 'within Oracle'? (You can also look at SQL Developer's log to see the SQL the export tool is running under the hood.)

Comment: Can't do a datapump. There is another system that manages the data movement, so I have to generate DML statements in order to make changes to the other server. That's a good idea to check the Developer's Log, I'll explore that some. Thanks for your help! If anyone else has any recommendations, this thread is still open